# How to create basic administrator component in Joomla3.1?

Tags: joomla

I am tried to create a basic component in joomla 3.1. But I am facing several problem.I know
to create component in joomla 2.5.Please help.

Comment: I am a professional mind reader.  I think you have an issue with using non-legacy inheritance which default to very different implementations on J3.1.  Oh please what kind of question is that?  You have several problems and you are too lazy to mention them?  It will be hard to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the Joomla Component Creator a try. http://www.component-creator.com

It allows you to build both Joomla 3.1 and 2.5 components. It is free to build simple components.